# Scroll to first selected Item in ASP.NET ListBox

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, asp.net-ajax, listbox

is there an easy way to scroll an ASP.Net ListBox automatically to the first selected Item?
The ListBox has SelectioMode="Multiple".

```
<asp:ListBox ID="LbSymptomCodesEdit" CausesValidation="true" ValidationGroup="VG_SAVE" Height="100%" Width="100%" runat="server"  SelectionMode="Multiple"></asp:ListBox>
```

The ListBox is in the EditItemTemplate of a FormView inside of an UpdatePanel.
jQuery is possible but it would be great if there would be an asp.net serverside(or Ajax) way to achieve this because i don't want to use more client scripts than really needed(and this is only a nice to have).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there is any server side method to achieve what you want to. For example, the ASP.Net Page option "MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback" and the validator's "SetFocusOnError" properties all inject a small amount of javascript into a page to manage this.

If you really want to be able to scroll to the first selected item, I suggest you inherit from ListBox and add code that will inject javascript (or jQuery) to control this for you.

Comment: It wouldnt be a problem to use scripts that are already available in the ajax library. I only want to minimize the client code that i have to register myself. Sometimes that causes other problems in a complex asp.net/ajax environment with Masterpages,UserControls,FormViews etc.

Comment: Ah I did not even consider the AJAX library as I tend to shy away from it. There may well be something in there that can aid you although off the top of my head I cannot think of something.